# How do I make my python script less laggy?

Tags: python, optimization, lag

I am new to python and I've just created this script :

```
import os
import os.path
import time

while True:
    if os.path.isfile('myPathTo/shutdown.svg'):
        os.remove('myPathTo/shutdown.svg')
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cd C:\Windows\PSTools & psshutdown -d -t 0')
```

As you can see, this script is very short and I think there is a way to make it less laggy. On my PC, it is using about 30% of my processor :

[Python stats on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmeRX.png)

I don't really know why it is using so much resources, I need your help :)
A little explanation of the program : 
I'm using IFTTT to send a file on my google drive which is synchronized on my pc (shutdown.svg) when I ask google home to shut down my pc.
When Python detect the file, he has to remove it and shut down the pc. I've added time between theses actions to make sure the script does not check the file too many times to reduce lag. Maybe 1 second is too short ?

Answer (score 1):

> I've added time between theses actions to make sure the script does not check the file too many times to reduce lag

This loop is sleeping 1 sec only before shutting down when the file is found, i.e. it never sleeps until it actually finds a file. So, put `sleep(1)` out of the if-condition.

> Maybe 1 second is too short?

If you can, make this sleep time as long as possible.

If your only task is to shut down the PC, there are so many ways of scanning for an update like crons for regular scripts running or setting a lightweight server